# An existing record overwritten by different process by insertion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have two processes (Process1 and Process2) and both inserts a record to TableA.

But for some reason, Process2 overwrote the record created by Process1 few seconds ago. TableA has IDENTITY column which is the primary key.

What would be the probable cause that this happened and how can I prevent it?

We are using Sql Server 2014.

- The DB load during that day and time was really heavy.

Comment: can you share some code or outline on how you are inserting

Comment: 1. Lock [not] in use  2. You are not using @SCOPE_IDENTITY inside a transaction   3. Any of the process updating anything?

Comment: Yes those 2 processes are not using lock. Process 2 is actually using @SCOPE_IDENTITY. Both processes inserts new records to other tables using id created in TableA.